# Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : could not find function "sim"

Tags: r

I was trying to learn R using a book. I was trying to do an example where for each row of the matrix, the corresponding element of the vector will be either 1 or 0, depending on whether the majority of the
first d elements in that row is 1 or 0. The code used was:-

```
copymaj <- function(rw,d) {
   maj <- sum(rw[1:d]) / d
   return(if(maj > 0.5) 1 else 0)
}

 x
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1    0    1    1    0
[2,]  1    1    1    1    0
[3,]  1    0    0    1    1
[4,]  0    1    1    1    0

apply(x,1,copymaj,3)
```

It is showing the above error. Also if I do `apply(x,1,copymaj(3))`, still error is shown.

R 2.13 is installed
Please help!

Comment: The command `apply(x,1,copymaj,3)` works for me.

Comment: Perhaps `sum` was misspelled? otherwise I know of a function `sim` in the `arm` package.

Comment: Probably so. Weirdly the code is working in R studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @BenBarnes pointed out, you probably misspelled `sum`, I think you wrote `sim` instead of `sum`.

I was able to reproduce your error by doing:

```
copymaj0 <- function(rw,d) {
  maj <- sim(rw[1:d]) / d    # here you have sim, this causes the error 
  return(if(maj > 0.5) 1 else 0)
}

copymaj1 <- function(rw,d) {
  maj <- sum(rw[1:d]) / d    # here you have sum which works well for me 
  return(if(maj > 0.5) 1 else 0)
}

x <- matrix(c(1,0,1,1,0,
         1,1,1,1,0,
         1,0,0,1,1,
         0,1,1,1,0), ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)

apply(x,1,copymaj0,3) # prints error
Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : could not find function "sim"

apply(x,1,copymaj1,3) # works well
[1] 1 1 0 1
```

I really think you misspelled `sum`.

`apply(x,1,copymaj1(3))` won't work becase if you read `?apply` you'll see 
`apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)`, then `apply(x,1,copymaj1(3))` wil produce an error because 
`...` replaces the arguments to `FUN` (`d=3` in your case) is missed. In order to pass optional arguments to your fun you have to use `...` as in `apply(x,1,copymaj1,3)` but not using `apply(x,1,copymaj1(3))`.

Comment: Thanks. That might have been the problem. But its sum and also its working in Rstudio but not in R GUI.